# Как правильно: «на GitHub» или «в GitHub»?

Tags: предлоги

Как правильно?

> исходные тексты доступны в GitHub

или

> исходные тексты доступны на GitHub

Answer (score 10):

Чтобы определить предлог, используемый с именем собственным, которое обозначает название фирмы или её продукта, необходимо подставить подходящее по смыслу нарицательное существительное. С именем собственным употребляется тот же предлог, что и с соответствующим ему именем нарицательным.

GitHub - это сайт (точнее, веб-сервис, но в приведённом Вами примере уместнее первое). Со словом "сайт" употребляется предлог "на". Следовательно, правильный вариант - "Исходники доступны на GitHub".

Впрочем, я часто встречала варианты, где "GitHub" склоняется. Только тогда название пишется кириллицей : "Исходники доступны на гитхабе".

Comment: скорее всего, всё-таки "гитхабе", а не "гитхубе" :)

Comment: Здесь может быть и другой уклон: "исходники доступны в репозитории GitHub".  Почему если "в репозитории" убрать, то сразу будет "на"?

Comment: @cnst, конечно =) сказывается чешское произношение, а по-русски будет "гитхаб" =)

Comment: @cnst, потому что там винительный падеж (в репозитории *чего?* GitHub). А если убрать "в репозитории", то винительный падеж не угадать, следовательно, применяются правила именительного (то есть, согласно контексту, речь идёт о самом сервисе, а не отдельном репозитории).

Answer (score 3):

According to Google:

- ["на github"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0+github%22) — 87,1k results;
- ["в github"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2+github%22) — 34,1k results.

On the other hand,

- ["доступны на github"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%BD%D0%B0+github%22) — 64.500 results;
- ["доступны в github"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D1%8B+%D0%B2+github%22) — 71 results.

So, «доступны на GitHub» is probably the correct way of saying this.

Comment: It doesn't mean something is better, it just means it is more frequent.

Comment: @sharptooth: So if something has 300 upvotes on stackoverflow.com, it isn't good ? ;) Granted, it's not a necessity, but most times, it is.

Comment: @Quandary: Upvotes are there because *someone decided to upvote* but one doesn't need a decision to blindly copy something.

Comment: Если вопрос задан по-русски, то и ответ желательно давать по-русски ;)

Answer (score 3):

Правильно `на Github`.

Для запоминания можно применять фразу `на [сайте] Github`. По-русски не скажут `в сайте` (это звучит неправильно), скажут `на сайте`.

Comment: А почему "на сайте", а не "в репозитории"? GitHub — всё-таки совсем не только [веб] сайт.

Comment: @cnst Потому что это просто мнемоническое правило, как можно запомнить. `в GitHub` для меня звучит неправильно.

Comment: Еще можно добавить, что в устной речи обычно GitHub склоняется: `на гитхабе`

Comment: @cnst Могу предположить, что GitHub - это в первую очередь сайт, и если не упоминается с ним сайт это или репозиторий, то по-умолчанию GitHub воспринимается как сайт (most salient interpretation), и поэтому предлог `на`.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что GitHub это не репозиторий. Это сайт с доступом к многим репозиториям